# Testing for density independence

Tags: android, testing, size, screen

After finishing the programming part of my app I want to test it with the Android Emulator.

1. I tried to make my app density independent an now I want to test it with different emulator devices. Which resolutions and screen sizes should I test? Do you have a list of virtual devices, which you use to test your application before releasing?
2. Which api-Levels should I test? (My application uses bluetooth).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the correct answer here is to 'test every possibility'. 
But this of course would be a huge job.

I usually take the Nexus devices as base lines, which will guide you through most of the possible and populair sizes.

Android versions you should check every one of them, starting with the version you want to support as lowest. Every version can react differently to not only your layout and styles, but also handle your java code differently .

You can find the Nexus devices and their sizes at http://developer.android.com/distribute/promote/device-art.html 
Be sure to press 'Older devices'

In addition to this, you could try to get your hands on some populair devices from other manufacturers like Samsung and HTC, since they also have a hand in changing the way your layout and styles will behave.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic bulletproof answer.

You can use this [Platform Versions](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) to glean some information about what are the most common API lvls, and device densities being used.

But ultimately the answer to your question depends largely upon your target audience and the devices that they carry. The best case scenario is to test on as many different configurations as possible =) starting of course with the most widely used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are designing an application, which is density specific, then you should test on all the possible densities. To test your application on various density device, you should have base device for each density for e.g Samsung Nexus - xhdpi, HTC One(hdpi) and similarly one base device for mdpi, ldpi. If you are also supporting Tablets have base device Tablets supporting different densities.
Additionally, you can avoid scaling with respect to device density by setting the following parameter in the manifest file supports-screens android:anyDensity=false